# Track button click as goal in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, google-analytics, goal-tracking

I have a button on my website, clicking on this button reveals a phonenumber.

**HTML**

```
<div class="call-wrapper-middle">
    <button id="call-phone-middle"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>Call us</button>
    <div class="call-number-middle" style="display: block;"> <a href="tel:555" class="number">555</a></div>
</div>
```

**Using the following jQuery**

```
(function($) {
  $("button#call-phone-middle").click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $("div.call-number-middle").show();
  });
})(jQuery);
```

This works great. But I also wish to track the clicks on the button as a goal in Google Analytics.

So I added `href="/show/phonenumber-middle" onclick="javascript:pageTracker._trackPageview (‘Phonenumber Middle’);" target="blank"` to the button:

```
<div class="call-wrapper-middle">
    <button href="/show/phonenumber-middle" onclick="javascript:pageTracker._trackPageview (‘Phonenumber Middle’);" target="blank" id="call-phone-middle"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>Call us</button>
    <div class="call-number-middle" style="display: block;"> <a href="tel:555" class="number">555</a></div>
</div>
```

And added a goal in Google Analytics with the following settings:.

Goal setup: `Custom`
Goal type: `Destination`
Destination; Equals to: `/show/phonenumber-middle`

Getting "This Goal would have a 0% conversion rate based on your data" and in the Real Time report there is no conversations.

My guess is that something is wrong with the `<button>` but I have no clue.

Comment: Are you seeing anything in the real time reports when you click the button?

Comment: Yes, I am seeing myself, 1 active user.

Comment: If you can see events come through in RT, then you may just need to wait for the data to be processed, and this takes up to 24 hours.

Comment: There no events triggering in the Real Time report.

Comment: I'm assuming you clicked the button and checked, and that you are not filtering your own visits as well?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I would use a Google Analytics *event* for this. [Here is the documentation for a GA click event](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events). Then in goals, you would set your goal type to event, and you can track it via the Category, Action, or Label attributes

```
<div class="call-wrapper-middle">
    <button href="/show/phonenumber-middle" onclick="__gaTracker('send', 'event', 'buttons', 'click', 'phone-number-middle');" target="blank" id="call-phone-middle" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>Call us</button>
    <div class="call-number-middle" style="display: block;"> <a href="tel:555" class="number">555</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: is it `onclick="__gaTracker(...` or `onclick="ga(...` like it says in the docs?

Comment: @AkinHwan for this specific case, it was `__gaTracker(...` because that's how it was loaded onto this specific site. For you, I would guess it is `ga(...`