# tracking button click as goal in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, google-analytics, goal-tracking

I am trying to do button click in GA, but getting this

```
This Goal would have a 0% conversion rate based on your data from the past 7 days.
```

Although in the Real Time report, there are conversations.

[I found this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31673991/track-button-click-as-goal-in-google-analytics) and I have done exactly this.

```
Goal type: Event

Event conditions:

Category; Equals to: button
Action; Equals to: click
Label; Equals to: trial-button
```

and this is my html

```
<a onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'trial-button');" href="https://www.ecanvasser.com/signup.php" target="_blank"><img src="/content/images/2016/10/button-1.PNG" alt="" title=""></a>
```

Unlike the user in that post, I am not using yoat plugin. but still its not working.

**UPDATE**

I just checked the GA and now it's showing

This Goal would have a 1.47% conversion rate based on your data from the past 7 days.
What does this mean? Does it mean that I have implemented it correctly ?

Comment: Do you have data in your event report showing up? In some GA properties it takes up to 48h for data to show up.
Is google analytics implemented correctly and available at the moment you test your clicks? Can you check your network protocol tab in Chrome developer tools?

Comment: In real-time events, yes it shows conversations. 

Test GA is implemented correnctly as there are stats from other pages. 

I checked network tab, GA is loading on button click.

Comment: You can also install GA Debugger (Chrome plugin) to verify that your hits are sent in the console. As mentioned already, it usually takes up to 48 hours for events to show up in your standard reports. Make sure you don't have anything set for the event value either.

Comment: GA is telling you 1.47% conversion as it is taking up data of this event definition and using it to calculate conversion.