# How to add google analytics on practo(external website button) button

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

Practo provides : `<practo:abs_widget widget="**********"></practo:abs_widget>`
need to add google analytics when user will click on button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have this solution:

```
<div class="call-wrapper-middle">
    <button href="/show/phonenumber-middle" onclick="__gaTracker('send', 'event', 'buttons', 'click', 'phone-number-middle');" target="blank" id="call-phone-middle" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>Call us</button>
    <div class="call-number-middle" style="display: block;"> <a href="tel:555" class="number">555</a></div>
</div>
```

The doc: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

The source: [Track button click as goal in Google Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31673991/track-button-click-as-goal-in-google-analytics)

Comment: Used like this : <practo:abs_widget widget="**********" onclick="__gaTracker('send', 'event', 'buttons', 'click', 'phone-number-middle');" id="call-phone-middle"></practo:abs_widget>. Working fine.